# Tightly coupled dependencies through callback argument types

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, guzzle

My example uses PHP, but the concept should apply to OOP in general.

I'm using the Dependency Injection pattern to decouple my classes and allow easy mocking and testing. For this concrete example, my example class `ApiConsumer` performs HTTP requests against an API using an HTTP client, which is injected in the constructor through an interface:

```
class ApiConsumer {
    private $client;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $client) {
        $this->client = $client;
    }
}

interface HttpClientInterface {
    public function async(string $method, string $uri, array $options, callable $success, callable $failure): void;
}
```

Now my issue is with those callbacks and parameter type hinting (in other languages, this would be an issue of type declaration).

One possible implementation of the interface is my class `Guzzle`, which wraps the GuzzleHttp library, a popular HTTP client lib for PHP. This class looks like this:

```
class Guzzle implements HttpClientInterface {
    private $client;
    private $promises;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
    }

    public function async(string $method, string $uri, array $options, callable $success, callable $failure): void {
        $this->promises[] = function () use ($method, $uri, $options, $success, $failure) {
            return $this->client->requestAsync($method, $uri, $options)->then($success, $failure);
        };
    }
}
```

So it essentially parks the request in the `$promises` array until at some point, another method is called that actually runs those requests, executing either the success or failure callback depending on the request's result.

This leads to a problem when I'm writing those callback functions. In order to properly type hint the things that will actually end up getting passed to those callbacks, I need to directly reference the types used by the GuzzleHttp library. For example, say I'm making an API request inside my `ApiConsumer` class like this:

```
    public function consumeSomeEndpoint(): void {
         $this->client->async(
             'GET', 
             'https://some.api.com/endpoint/', 
             [],
             function (Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response) {
                 var_dump($response);
             },
             function (GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $reason) {
                 echo $reason->getResponse()->getBody();
                 throw new RuntimeException($reason->getMessage());
             },
         );
    }
```

The `ResponseInterface` is fine, that's general enough that it can be used in many places (the entire `Psr` package is essentially just providing HTTP related interfaces). The `BadResponseException`, however, is specific to GuzzleHttp. If I want to create an alternate implementation of an `HttpClientInterface`, I have to actually import the GuzzleHttp lib just so I can understand those exceptions. I can't introduce an interface here because obviously the lib's Exceptions don't implement it. The interface implemented by `BadResponseException`, `Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface\RequestExceptionInterface`, doesn't provide the `getResponse()` method used to access the response payload, which contains potential information from the API about the reason for the failure.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: *I can't introduce an interface here because obviously the lib's Exceptions don't implement it* - actually in this case, they do. PSR provides [`RequestExceptionInterface`](https://github.com/php-fig/http-client/blob/master/src/RequestExceptionInterface.php) for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the way around this is to depend in an exception that is not tightly bound to the library, and that other replacements can either throw or implement.

Luckily, that's the case for Guzzle.

`GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException` extends `GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException`, which in turns implements `Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface\RequestExceptionInterface`;

As seen, [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Exception/BadResponseException.php#L11) and [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/34bc199aef77ff1c13f7126c0464f8fa9ee55f9f/src/Exception/RequestException.php#L15):

```
/**
 * Exception when an HTTP error occurs (4xx or 5xx error)
 */
class BadResponseException extends RequestException
{ /** class omitted **}
```

```
/**
 * HTTP Request exception
 */
class RequestException extends TransferException implements RequestExceptionInterface
{ /** class omitted **}
```

To type-hint properly the ecallback, you probably have to specify [`Psr\Http\Client\ClientExceptionInterface`](https://github.com/php-fig/http-client/blob/22b2ef5687f43679481615605d7a15c557ce85b1/src/ClientExceptionInterface.php#L8), since that's the most generic one in the PSR contract, and conforming implementations might throw any of the extended exceptions: `NetworkExceptionInterface` or `RequestExceptionInterface`, mentioned earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately, the interface doesn't provide `getResponse()`, which I need in order to access the full error message in the response payload. For some reason, Guzzle truncates error messages to the point of uselessness. I guess I'll have to wrap my callback inside the Guzzle wrapper and rewrite the exceptions :/